# How do I change size of app icons in Activity Overview?

Tags: gnome

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish development branch). As soon as I installed, I noticed that the icons present in "Show Applications" are smaller than expected (i.e. smaller than that used to be in other versions). So here it is:
[image: Icon Image]

As you can see here, the icons are too small and, yes, its too hard to read its name because some apps name comes in like five lines. Is there a way I can increase their size? Or do I have to stick like this?

Comment: Hello. 22.04 does not exist yet and therefore is off topic on this site.

Comment: So where should I ask it?? I can't live with this kind of small items.

Comment: You can report it as a bug but it is still being developed so you will have to live with it that way till they change it if they change it.

Comment: Ok thank you...

Comment: @Jhon since this IS linux...you can change anything...as long as you know what files to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Good news is, I've found an easy fix.

I found this GNOME extension named "App Grid Tweaks". The GNOME extensions website shows that it's currently incompatible with GNOME 42, but I found that manually downloading the extension and installing it using terminal works just fine. You can get the extension from [here](https://github.com/Selenium-H/App-Grid-Tweaks).
If you're having compatibility issues, try downloading from the [experimental branch](https://github.com/Selenium-H/App-Grid-Tweaks/tree/experimental).

After enabling the extension, you can tweak the settings to your liking.
Here are my settings:

[image: settings]

and my results:

[image: results]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately, in Ubuntu 22.04 `gnome-shell-extensions` doesn't allow to turn the extension on, saying it is outdated.

Comment: @AndrewLukjanov You can try downloading from the experimental branch at https://github.com/Selenium-H/App-Grid-Tweaks/tree/experimental

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Answer (score -2):

Install GNOME Tweak, in Fonts, set scale factor to 0.85 then increase font size to 12

Comment: Answer not very helpful